# Is it possible to keep all special letters for foreign languages in slug as in title?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

Is it possible to keep special letters in slug for foreign languages as in title?

When you visit https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oliven%C3%B6l you can see that the url contains a special letter. Is it possible to have the same functionality in WordPress for foreign languages?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any decent theme or plugin will run URLs through the [`esc_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url/) function to ensure the string is a decent URL. As you can see, there is a filter at the end of that function which allows you to change the outcome. You could use that to put special characters in the URL or even undo the whole escaping process.

Please beware that escaping is not done for nothing. Apart from preventing invalid URLs it also solves [security issues](https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/) with code injected through 
a URL.

Comment: Hmm, preventing themes from escaping the URLs won't help, I guess. The slugs still will get sanitized, won't they?